# msinfo32 won't run in NSIS under Windows XP

Tags: windows, nsis, msinfo32

The following NSIS line refuses to run for some reason (returns immediately) under Windows XP:

```
  ExecWait ' "$PROGRAMFILES\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSInfo\msinfo32" /report "$DESKTOP\msinfo.log" '
```

If I run msinfo32 in the command line, it runs properly:

> C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Admin> "%PROGRAMFILES%\Common
>   Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\MSInfo\msinfo32" /report
>   "%APPDATA%\..\Desktop\msinfo.log"

Why?

And how do I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove spaces after single quotes and add .exe for msinfo. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
ExecWait '"$COMMONFILES\Microsoft Shared\MSInfo\msinfo32" /report "$temp\msinfo.log"'
```

Like sha says, remove whitespace, and you should be using the $COMMONFILES[32/64] constant, not $PROGRAMFILES