# What is the best way to compress a text file from within an NSIS script?

Tags: compression, nsis

Assuming that it is possible to compress a file from within an NSIS script, what is the best way to accomplish that and what would be the actual statement?

Is there a built-in NSIS instruction for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not really make a lot of sense, are you asking how to install a file, or are you trying to use NSIS as some sort of general file compression utility?

Here is a basic script that "installs" a file:

```
Outfile test.exe
Requestexecutionlevel user
Setcompressor LZMA
Page instfiles

Section
;Not a good idea to hardcode the destination like this, 
;normally you would use a directory page so the user can choose
SetOutPath "c:\SaveToThisFolder"

;Take thefile.txt from the system you compile on and output it on the end users system 
;into the directory specified by the SetOutPath call
File "thefile.txt"
Sectionend
```

If you are writing an actual installer for some application, you really should take a look at some of the [examples](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Examples/example2.nsi) that ship with NSIS

Comment: I am asking about the latter, trying to use NSIS to compress a file that was generated by NSIS (not really a general file compression utility). For example, compressing the text file that is produced by msinfo32: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597125/msinfo32-wont-run-in-nsis-under-windows-xp

Comment: @Eternal Learner: This will require external tools (7zip,pkzip etc), extract desired tool to $pluginsdir and use a plugin like nsExec to run it.

Comment: No problem. I just wanted to make sure that I am not missing an NSIS built-in function.